# Mongoose populates field with null

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema:

```
  mongoose.Schema({
    state: {
        type: {
           action: 'string' , 
           user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: 'User'}, 
           at: 'date'
       },
   default: {}
   },
   log: [{
           action: 'string' , 
           user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
           ref: 'User'}, 
           at: 'date'
       }]
})
```

Trying to populate it

```
Model.findById(id).populate('state.user').populate('log.user').exec(cb)
```

In query result "user" field of log items is populated correctly **and "state.user" is null**. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple embedded objects like `state`, define the structure without using `type`:

```js
mongoose.Schema({
    state: {
       action: 'string' , 
       user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
       at: 'date'
    },
    log: [{
           action: 'string' , 
           user: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
           at: 'date'
    }]
})
```

`populate('state.user')` should work fine with that.

Comment: I just wanted to have a default value, I seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

In your schema, you have `state.type.user`, but your call to `populate` refers to `state.user`. The path in the populate call doesn't match the schema.

It should be `Model.findById(id).populate('state.type.user').populate('log.user').exec(cb)`